# showing multiple graphs in the same image on python

Tags: python, dataframe, subplot

I am trying the 'pivot' feature with categorical variables in relation to the 'weight' variable after creating my own database.
I would like to show all graphs in the same image but the following
code prints them all separately, and when I uncomment the "plt.subplot()" line I still get separate graphs
but smaller and empty.
What should I do to show all graphs within the same image?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
 
 
data = [['tom', 10,6,'brown',200], ['nick', 15,5.10,'red',150], ['juli', 14,5.5,'black',170]
        ,['peter', 10,6,'blue',290], ['axel', 15,5.10,'yellow',190], ['william', 14,5.5,'yellow',170]
        ,['tom', 10,6,'orange',100], ['thomas', 15,5.10,'brown',150], ['angela', 14,5.5,'black',160]
        ,['peter', 10,6,'purple',220], ['nick', 15,5.10,'orange',150], ['aroon', 14,5.5,'red',170] ]
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Age','height','color','weight'])
 
 
categorical_variables= (df.select_dtypes('object').iloc[0:0] ) # categorical variables
categ_var_list=(list(categorical_variables)[:])
print(categ_var_list)
 
count=0
 
for i in categ_var_list:
    count+=1
 
    condition_pivot = df.pivot_table(index=i, values='weight', aggfunc=np.median)
    condition_pivot.plot(kind='bar', color='blue')
 
    plt.xlabel(categ_var_list[count-1])
    plt.ylabel('weight')
    plt.xticks(rotation=0)
 
    #plt.subplot(2,1,count)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pyplots.subplots](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html):

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(2,1)
 
for ax_i,i in enumerate(categ_var_list):

    condition_pivot = df.pivot_table(index=i, values='weight', aggfunc=np.median)
    condition_pivot.plot(kind='bar', color='blue',ax=ax[ax_i],rot=0)

    ax[ax_i].set_ylabel('weight')
    
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Since you are melting the data, you can also use seaborn

```
import seaborn as sns
g = sns.FacetGrid(df[['Name','color','weight']].melt(id_vars="weight"), 
                  row="variable",sharex=False,sharey=False,aspect=1.7)
g.map(sns.barplot, "value", "weight",estimator=np.median,ci=None)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.     In your first code, is there anyway that the label font can be made smaller? Or a way to optimize the space as much as possible? Since I would like to apply this code to a large dataset and 'fig.tight_layout()' does not always work.

Comment: something like ```ax[ax_i].set_ylabel('weight',fontsize=5)```